# Word: How to copy User Assigned keyboard shortcuts to another computer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to copy Word 2007 **User Assigned** keyboard shortcuts to another system?

(Right now I am manually setting them up again.)

If not, then is there a way to tell what keyboard shortcuts were set up by the user?

This way I will be able to set them all up at once, instead of waiting until they are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [Files and Settings Transfer Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA011886681033.aspx) meet your needs?

(I hope you don't mind that I won't take a bunch of space copy/pasting what's in the link.  The complete description and instructions are available there.)

Answer (score 1):

I have just looked through the configuration settings for the File and Settings Transfer Wizard as I know that moves them... It looks like all user related settings are created and kept in the word12.pip file located in

(Vista & 7)

```
    %userprofile%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\office\
(Above should work, but for actual path... if my username is Wil)
    c:\users\wil\appdata\roaming\microsoft\office
```

(XP)

```
    %userprofile%\local settings\application data\roaming\microsoft\office\
(Above should work, but for actual path... if my username is Wil)
    c:\users\wil\local settings\application data\roaming\microsoft\office
```

(p.s. please tell me if I am wrong, been a while since I have used XP and just trying to remember the paths - I think that is where it should be.)